# Changing the date string format

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Hello Sed/Bash/Awk experts,

I have a file full of dates in the following format:

```
Feb 5 2015

Nov 25 2014

Apr 16 2015
```

What I would like is to convert them to this format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

So they should look like this:

```
2015-02-05

2014-11-25

2015-04-16
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
date -f dates.txt +%Y-%m-%d
```

In the `-f` option you can provide your input file with one date per line.

Comment: This is the only sensible option.

Comment: Didn't know about `-f` - that's an eye-opener!

Comment: simple and genius. Thank you!

Comment: I'm amazed there's an option for `date` to handle the case where you have a file of just dates, nothing else. I guess it happens given this question though!

Answer (score 4):

Using awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{x="  JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC"}
     {printf "%04d-%02d-%02d\n",$3,index(x,toupper($1))/3,$2}' file
```

Comment: Very nice. I was thinking to make a big array but indexing is perfect for this.

Answer (score 2):

the `date` command is your friend here:

```
date --date="Feb 5 2015" +"%Y-%m-%d"
2015-02-05
```

so, you can say:

```
$ cat my_file | while read -r dt
> do
> date --date="${dt}" +"%Y-%m-%d"
> done
2015-02-05
2014-11-25
2015-04-16
```

Comment: UUOC and missing `IFS=` to prevent word splitting and see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219 for why using a shell loop just to manipulate text is to be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

paste the following:

```
{
    month="00";
    mon=toupper($1);
         if(mon=="JAN") month="01";
    else if(mon=="FEB") month="02";
    else if(mon=="MAR") month="03";
    else if(mon=="APR") month="04";
    else if(mon=="MAY") month="05";
    else if(mon=="JUN") month="06";
    else if(mon=="JUL") month="07";
    else if(mon=="AUG") month="08";
    else if(mon=="SEP") month="09";
    else if(mon=="OCT") month="10";
    else if(mon=="NOV") month="11";
    else if(mon=="DEC") month="12";
    printf("%s-%s-%02d\n", $3, month, $2)
}
```

into a file (We'll refer to the filename as [script_filename]
execute the following: 
    `awk -F' ' -E [script_filename] [date_filename]`
Where [date_filename] refers to the file which contains the dates you wish to convert.

Comment: fixed month numbers :P

Comment: Thanks for the printf gotcha! The -E option is infact the posix short option I tested this on Ubuntu trusty. 

About the -F' ': I try to be as specific as possible to prevent other unexpected behaviour. The op's example indicates he expects all instance formatted with a single space.

Comment: All your months after january are off by one.

Comment: Good to know about `-E`, thanks! Working on OS X as well. Personally, I still wouldn't set `FS`, although I certainly see your point.

Comment: I'd never heard of `-E` so I just googled it and apparently it's like `-f` but it disallows other normal awk functionality like assigning variables in the file list. While useful in CGI scripts apparently, `-f` is the normal way to introduce a script file in all awks. You need to make the 2nd `%d` in your `printf` either `%s` or `%2d` so the singe digit month numbers are printed as 2 digits.